# Eliminar el índice y comillas de un Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Realicé una matriz en python de la siguiente manera:

```
    Level   Descripcion                         Item Total             Linea
0   400     "MONTEFRIO CHORIZO SANTARROSANO "   674  T. Carnes Frias    1
1   400     "LA ESPANOLA SALCHICHA VIENA 26 "   704  T. Carnes Frias    1
2   400     "LAS CARNES DEL SEBASTIAN COSTI "   710  T. Carnes Frias    1
3   400     "CASABLANCA SURTIDO MIX MADURAD "   1067 T. Carnes Frias    1
4   400     "RICA RONDO SALCHICHON RES/POLL "   1071 T. Carnes Frias    1
5   400     "EL POZO JAMON IBERICO 70GR (SU "   1527 T. Carnes Frias    1
6   400     "DAN GALANTINA 420GR            "   1529 T. Carnes Frias    1
...
```

Necesito eliminar las comillas de la columna `Descripcion`. He utilizado el comando `.Descripcion.replace('"', '')`, pero no me funciona.

Además también necesito eliminar la primera columna del Data Frame que es el índice como tal.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que en primer lugar debes acceder a los valores de las cadenas mediante [`Series.str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) para luego poder aplicar el [`replace()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace)

```
df['Descripcion'] = df['Descripcion'].str.replace('"','')
```

o bien:

```
df.Descripcion= df.Descripcion.str.replace('"', '*')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió bastante